# Setting hidden sections in beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning, hide

I would like to hide some sections in Beamer so that I can adapt the presentation for different situations.

Notice that `\section*` hides the section from the table of contents, but the section still appears in the PDF.

I can set `<presentation:0>` to hide specific slides. But I have to do this for all slides in a section to hide the section. Is there an equivalent of `<presentation:0>` to hide an entire section?

MWE

```
\documentclass[t,aspectratio=169]{beamer} % 12pt, handout

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Main}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Main}
\begin{itemize}
\item Points in the main section
\item This section will always be used
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Additional}

\begin{frame}
% \begin{frame}<presentation:0> % I could do this for this slide, but I would have to repeat it for all slides in the section.
\frametitle{Additional}
\begin{itemize}
\item Points in the additional section
\item Can this entire section be made hidden?
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Page 1] [image: Page 2] [image: Page 3]

Thank you

Comment: I wonder if something like the https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beameraudience would be helpful for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `\mode<presentation:0>` before your section to hide the whole section and switch back to normal content with `\mode*`:

```
\documentclass[t,aspectratio=169]{beamer} % 12pt, handout

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Main}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Main}
\begin{itemize}
\item Points in the main section
\item This section will always be used
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\mode<presentation:0>
\section{Additional}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Additional}
\begin{itemize}
\item Points in the additional section
\item Can this entire section be made hidden?
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\mode*

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: This is very good. Thank you

Comment: @Andre You're welcome!